# Rank of this matrix with a parameter: explanation about losing information

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank, gaussian-elimination

Consider the following matrix, where $k$ is a real parameter:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & k & 1 \\ k & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & k \end{pmatrix}$$

I know I can study the zeroes of the determinant and so on. But I want to use Gauss reduction to study the rank.

So I start with $R_2 - k R_1$, with the condition $k \neq 0$ and $R_3 - R_1$, getting

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & k & 1 \\ 0 & 1-k^2 & 1-k \\ 0 & 1-k & k-1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Now the big question: I could normally go with $(1+k)R_3 - R_2$ to obtain

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & k & 1 \\ 0 & 1-k^2 & 1-k \\ 0 & 0 & k^2 + k - 2 \end{pmatrix}$$

And observe that the last row is null iff $k = 1$ or $k = -2$. Then I can conclude the rank is two for $k = -2$ and one for $k = 1$. So far so good.

- My big question is this: let's say I don't think much, and I notice that, right after the very first reductio, I could multiply both the second and third row by $\frac{1}{1-k}$ assuming $k\neq 1$. I would then get

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & k & 1 \\ 0 & 1+k & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Now this time there is no way to get a rank less than two (for $k = -2$ I can still get the rank equals to two).

So the idea of dividing by $1-k$ makes things wrong.

Why so? In what way should I avoid this operation, which apparently sounds legit to me in the same way at the beginning I did $R_2 - k R_1$ with $k\neq 0$?

Thank you so much!

Comment: In your second approach, you can still get rank $2$. What if $k=-2$?

Comment: @AnuragA You're right, I was thinking of $k = 2$ indeed. Going to edit this part!

Comment: There is nothing wrong in the second approach, you just have to analyze the case for $k=1$ (the assumption you made when you divided by $k-1$) separately. The answer is same from both approaches: $k=1 \implies r(A)=1, k=-2 \implies r(A)=2$ and for all other $k$'s, the rank is $3$.

Comment: @AnuragA Oh, ok!! Thank you again!